# I am trying to fix this command to allow speech recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()     # a recogniser to understand my voice 

with sr.Microphone() as source: # use the default microphone as the voice
        print('Listening....')
        voice = r.listen(source) # call speech recogniser to recognise the first phrase
try:        
    command = r.recognizer_google(voice) #  pass the audio to google
    print(command)
except:
    print('Could Not Understand Audio')
```

However i am getting this error returned

```
Instance of 'Recognizer' has no 'recognizer_google' member
```

Can someone help me fix this ? I have downgraded to python 3.8.1 from 3.8.2 but the problem persists

Comment: Python 8.1? You must be talking about something else

Comment: updated it to reflect python 3.8.2 and 3.8.1 :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005310/speech-recognition-python-code-not-working

Comment: Thank you for the update however it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I've decided to take out the r.recognizer_google section

Comment: I'm getting this error now Module 'Speech_Recognition' has no 'WaitTimeoutError' member

Answer (score 1):

You should check the version of `speech_recognition` library. The version that you are using doesn't seem to have  `recognizer_google` function.

Comment: Seems they have discontinued it and you can only use the google cloud API is that correct ?

Comment: I still get the same error Instance of 'Recognizer' has no 'recognize_google_cloud' member

Comment: even though that is in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()     # a recogniser to understand my voice 

with sr.Microphone() as source: # use the default microphone as the voice
        print('Listening....')
        voice = r.listen(source) # call speech recogniser to recognise the first phrase
try:        
    command = r.recognize_google(voice) #  pass the audio to google
    print(command)
except:
    print('Could Not Understand Audio')
```

**The Error You Have Done Here:**

1. There isn't any member called `r.recognizer_google()` but there is a member called `r.recognize_google()` in the `Recognizer()`
2. It is best if you upgrade your version of python to the newest, as well as the `speech_recognition` module, if the above code didn't work