# Speech recognition using the speech_recognition module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition

I'm having trouble with this code, i have all the needed requirements downloaded, butt it hust gives me a blinking pointer.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r=sr.Recognizer()
print(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names())
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    # r.energy_threshold()
    print("say anything : ")
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source,duration=2)
    audio= r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print(text)
    except:
        print("sorry, could not recognise")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [speech recognition python code not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005310/speech-recognition-python-code-not-working)

Comment: no it doesn't i tried that, but it still won't work